# inputs don't work on IE

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I wrote a js calculator with jquery, and it works on major browsers except IE, where the main problem is that the input elements don't show at all and input can not be displayed at them.
The inputs are disabled to prevent illegal input, I thought that may be the reason but enabling them doe's not solve it.
The code is at https://github.com/ZackYovel/jQCalc/tree/master/pathTo and a demo is at http://jqcalc.co.nf/
also here is the css for the inputs:
the inputs are wrapped with this div:

```
#jQCalc-input-container:focus {
    border: thin solid #fff;
    background: rgb(237,247,253); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(237,247,253,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(237,247,253,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(237,247,253,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(237,247,253,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(237,247,253,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(237,247,253,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#edf7fd', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

and these are the inputs:

```
#jQCalc-expression-line, #jQCalc-result-line {
    display: table-row;
    background: none;
    width: 95%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#jQCalc-result-line {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 14pt;
}

#jQCalc-expression-line {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Please post some code in here, enough to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Are you applying `display: table-row` to an input? if so I would bet this would cause a problem in IE, possibly other browsers too.

Comment: what versions of IE do you need to support and what versions have you tested?

Comment: pebbl, don't you wan't to make it an answer? it would make a good one. Can you tell my why table-row causes this?

Answer (score 0):

It's only going to work in IE8 or greater, take a look here for website compatibility:

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/css2/display.html

Also, notice your display: table-row element, needs to be nested inside a display: table element. Some other browsers might just be auto-correcting this for you.

I would avoid using display: table in my opinion because of this. You should usually be able to achieve the layout you want without it with a css grid like system with more compatibility.